# Result of ST_Contains gives false positive

Tags: mysql, mysql-spatial

I am trying to figure out the state that Berlin is in. So now my query `SELECT * FROM states WHERE ST_Contains(Geo, Point(13.383068, 52.530644));` return two results. One for Berlin which is correct, but also Brandenburg which is surrounding Berlin. See the attached graphics.
So it seems that `ST_Contains` does not account for the hole inside.

Currently the geospatial column is of datatype MulitPolygon.

Is there any other my-sql function that I can use to only find the correct state?

[image]

Comment: does your hole have the right orientation?

Comment: I got if from here: http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_wkt.py?id=62504&params=0. Not sure what you mean by right orientation?

Comment: I forget for mysql outers are clockwise and holes are anti-clockwise or the other way round. check the docs

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to reverse the result I get from openstreetmap?

Comment: You should test your geometry with `ST_IsValid()` If the internal ring doesn't have clockwise rotation (opposite of the external counter-clockwise rotation), then it's an invalid overlapping exterior ring, which would generate strange topology errors.

Comment: Can somebody tell me how to verify the hole orientation? And also... is there a way to correct it automatically if it's wrong?
The shape can be found here: http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/index.py?id=62504
Any help is greatly appreciated!!!
I'd love to know how I need to import the geometry in order for a correct ST_Contains result...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `contains` is not standard compliant. It does not use a precise object shape, just a boundary box.

So it "ignore" holes too.

Take a look at this thread for a MySQL or PostGIS solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394645/mysql-spatial-contains-shows-wrong-result